# Right align a youtube video

Tags: posts, css, html, visual-editor, youtube

I'm trying to right align (class="alignright") a YouTube video AND allow my client to edit the surrounding text in the future using the visual editor. I simply added class="alignright" to the  tag containing the embed using the HTML editor however when any changes are made to the text using the visual editor WordPress strips the extra code. I think it might be impossible to get the result that I want but could anyone confirm my suspicions or give me a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an id and CSS selector for the element and align it in your stylesheet.

Comment: Do you mean that WordPress will not strip an id the way it strips the class ?

Comment: No, I mean do it from outside of the post via external style sheet, so you don't have to worry about the stripping of code. So target the object for that post id.